# Can I prove (s : Stream a) -> (head s :: tail s = s) in Idris?

Tags: lazy-evaluation, idris

The following Idris proof doesn’t typecheck.

```hs
hts : (s : Stream a) -> (head s :: tail s = s)
hts (x::xs) = Refl
```

The error I get is:

```hs
    Type mismatch between
            x :: Delay xs = x :: Delay xs
    and
            x :: Delay (tail (x :: Delay xs)) = x :: Delay xs
```

A similar proof for non-empty `Vect`s typechecks just fine:

```hs
import Data.Vect
htv : (s : Vect (S k) a) -> (head s :: tail s = s)
htv (x::xs) = Refl
```

So I’m guessing the issue is in the laziness of `Stream`.

---

My working theory is that Idris doesn’t like simplifying whatever is inside of `Delay`, because it might get into an infinite loop that way. However, I want to coerce Idris to dip its toes in anyway, as the definition of `Prelude.Stream.tail` guarantees that the LHS would then reduce to `x :: Delay xs`, completing my proof.

Is my suspicion correct? And can I fix the proof somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done. I used an auxiliary congruence lemma:

```
%default total

consCong : {xs, ys : Stream a} -> (x : a) -> xs = ys -> x :: xs = x :: ys
consCong _ Refl = Refl
```

to prove the main lemma:

```
hts : (s : Stream a) -> (head s :: tail s = s)
hts (x :: xs) = consCong _ $ Refl
```

Comment: I couldn't get the standard `cong` lemma to work in this case.